# Using a Belkin USB dongle in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, usb, bluetooth

I recently aquired a "Belkin Mini Bluetooth® V4.0 USB Adapter", in hope that I could use it on my laptop, as a replacement for the one that disappeared.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to list under `hcitool`. I tried googling around, but the only results I find refer to [an old question on askubuntu.com](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174949&p=12887525#post12887525), dating back to 2013. It states that the following should fix the issue, as "it is supported, but the ID isn't recognized".

```
modprobe btusb 
echo "050d 065a" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id
```

I of course tried the above, but with no change.

For the record, `lsusb` has this to say about the dongle:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 050d:065a Belkin Components F8T065BF Mini Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
```

Replugging it results in `dmesg` reporting this about it:

```
[  758.594562] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  758.690858] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=050d, idProduct=065a
[  758.690866] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  758.690869] usb 1-1.2: Product: BCM20702A0
[  758.690872] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[  758.690875] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 5CF3707C8AF1
```

Using Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, kernel 3.13.0-37-generic

Comment: I found [this answer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R20HQ2X8G80YOY/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B009IQB3US&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=340831031&store=computers) in an Amazon review. The answer is for Debian, but it should work for its derivatives, including Mint. If you can't find a solution, you should try another dongle: they are so cheap that you can easily spend a lot more effort than it's worth in trying to interface it.

Comment: @AFH indeed, they are cheap, but delivery times can be long here in the middle of nowhere. Hoever, he amazon review did the trick - Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R20HQ2X8G80YOY/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B009IQB3US&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=340831031&store=computers) in an Amazon review. The answer is for Debian, but it should work for its derivatives, including Mint.

In essence, you need to create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local-bluetooth.rules` by adding the line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="050d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="065a", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'modprobe btusb; echo 050d 065a > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id'"
```

Then restart the `udev` service with `/etc/init.d/udev restart` or reboot. You will need root access for the edit and restart operations.